# Is there a way to copy response body to the clipboard in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Firebug allows you to copy the response body to the clipboard via a context menu item. Does Chrome dev tools have a similar feature? If so, where is it located?

Comment: Chrome DevTools doesn’t seem to have this feature. You should submit a feature request to http://webkit.org/new-inspector-bug

Comment: I submitted it here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159317

Comment: Write a web scraper for DevTools :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Under `Network`, right click on the request, select `Copy Response`.

---

[image]

---

Using Chrome 40.0.2214.93

Comment: This doesn't work all the time. I'm getting an empty copy. Seems like there's a bug with it.

Comment: Copy Request contained the same data differently organised as what I wanted in the right bottom panel in Chromium Developer Tools. Could not copy directly from that panel, so a related problem to the one described here by Pacerier.

Answer (score 1):

Under Elements, then in the left pane, right click the element you are interested in, e.g. body tag, click COPY as HTML

Comment: Not what the OP is asking for I believe.  The HTTP response (e.g. the contents of a javascript file the browser is fetching, or a JSON response to an AJAX request) is not at all the same thing as (and not always visible inside) the page DOM ("source").

Answer (score 1):

The below wouldn't happen to be what you're asking about?

[image: Selecting and copying from HTTP Response body]

Using Chrome 23.0.1271.52 beta-m

Comment: Responses are often too big for this method.

Comment: @thorn **NO** they're not. Select the first few characters, then `Shift+Ctrl+End` then `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: @vladr, Sometimes the response wouldn't even shown on that tab.